# Loop through array contain objects and create different arrays from it

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of objects and I need to produce arrays from it to be that every array contains the [user name] and the sum of his [length] the length is time in seconds.

What's the best way for it?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [length] => 4658
            [user_id] => 1922053
            [user_name] => Walled
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [length] => 5
            [user_id] => 1922053
            [user_name] => Walled
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [length] => 5555
            [user_id] => 19220
            [user_name] => Michael
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [length] => 2552
            [user_id] => 19220
            [user_name] => Michael
        )
)
```

Comment: I'd be creating a new array, and for each loop of your source array, using the name or id as the key, if the key is not yet defined in your new array, store the length value under that username key, if the key does exist, then add the length to the existing value.

Comment: Can you please write the example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will process the old array into a new one, It uses the user_id as the key of the new array so it can check if it is creating a new occurance or just adding the length to an existing occurance in the new array

```
$array = [
    (object)['length' => 4658, 'user_id' => 1922053, 'user_name' => 'Walled'],
    (object)['length' => 5, 'user_id' => 1922053, 'user_name' => 'Walled'],
    (object)['length' => 5555, 'user_id' => 19220, 'user_name' => 'Michael'],
    (object)['length' => 2552, 'user_id' => 19220, 'user_name' => 'Michael']
];

$new = [];
foreach( $array as $a ) {
    if ( ! array_key_exists($a->user_id, $new) ) {
        $new[$a->user_id] = $a;    
    } else {
        echo $new[$a->user_id]->length . PHP_EOL;
        $new[$a->user_id]->length += $a->length;    
    }
    
}

print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [1922053] => stdClass Object
        (
            [length] => 4663
            [user_id] => 1922053
            [user_name] => Walled
        )
    [19220] => stdClass Object
        (
            [length] => 8107
            [user_id] => 19220
            [user_name] => Michael
        )
)
```